# Return Objects created while parsing an XML Document

Tags: java, xml, return, xmlreader

So I want to read data from an xml file, I am now at a point where I have `XMLReader` and `ContentHandler` in place and when the `endDocument()` is fired I have "collected" all the data I need from the document.

But now it seems that I ran into a wall...

How do I return the collected data (from the `ContentHandler`) so that it can be used in my application?

Comment: As the name suggest (`ContentHanlder`), it's an handler. And we don't return from a handler but handle some events as they occur. You can see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html, all the methods' return type is void. May be what you can do is save (or push) it some where or do whatever you need to do with it from within the handler.

Comment: that much I have realised by now I am just searching for an elegant way to use my data and furthermore tell my application what to do next.

Comment: Well then you need to update your post (may with some relevant code) to reflect what you are really trying to do in your application after you are done collecting the data. Because right now it's impossible to guess what you really intend to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a `List<T>` in ContentHandler.

```
public class MyTextHandler implements ContentHandler {
  ....
  private ArrayList<YourModel> list;

  public MyTextHandler() {
    list= new ArrayList<YourModel>();
  }
  public ArrayList<YourModel> getList() {
    return list;
  }
  ....
}
```

Obtain list from the Handler:

```
MyTextHandler handler=new MyTextHandler();
reader.setContentHandler(handler);
InputSource is = new InputSource(filename);
reader.parse(is);

ArrayList<YourModel> list=handler.getList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically ...

You dont really "return" data from a ContentHandler - the content handler is not designed to fulfill any specific input/output contract.  Rather , it is an object which is supposed to "act" on XML data read actions.  Some ContentHandlers may not interact with the host application - they might just print data to the console, for example.  Meanwhile, others might process XML objects as beans, and then serialize those beans to a database.

If you want your application to "depend" directly on a ContentHandler to create objects, then the ContentHandler might typically be a subclass in your application which accesses the Model of your application, and writes data to that model.  By "Model" here, Im referring to the M in a typical MVC application.

The Practical Answer

The contentHandler interface is meant to define the behavior of your SAX parser.. The data is often created on the endDocument() method, wherein we dump all the XML data out to a database, or as print statements.

Comment: That might just be the kick in the right direction ... will have some decent sleep now and try to give my application a useful structure tomorrow, because although I "know" MVC I think I never really came to understand how to use it elegantly, but I think google knows. Thanks for you response!

Comment: Good -also, see The next question... Which  is a little more concrete : the"M" is the List being returned, and the handler is encapsulating the model.